# Does this element exist?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I want to know if an element exist on the page that I'm scraping with puppeteer.
I use this code inside this function, but it doesn't work:

```
let build = await page.evaluate(() =>{
let rune = document.querySelector('#selector') == null ? false : document.querySelector('#selector').src
return rune;
})
```

It always returns false, even when the element exists and should return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call your await function in async. Probably it calls function before it is loaded.

```
    (async () => {
let build = await page.evaluate(() =>{
let rune = document.querySelector('#selector') == null ? false : document.querySelector('#selector').src
return rune;
})
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seem to work properly.

**Inside a full example:**

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function fn() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, waituntil: 'domcontentloaded' })
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  await page.goto('http://example.com/')
  try {
    let build = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let rune = document.querySelector('h1') === null ? false : document.querySelector('h1').textContent
      return rune
    })
    console.log(build)

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }

  await browser.close()
}
fn()
```

*Note:* It is better to use the strict equality operatory in the ternary if you want to check if it is true or false.

**Output:**

```
Example Domain
```

**You may have a page that takes time to load the desired element.** You can force it to wait a bit with `await page.waitFor(5000) // in ms`. So your script won't need to wait for a specific selector (like `page.waitForselector('#selector')`) and won't fail if the element does not exist.

Another approach that may be more suitable for such usecases:

```js
if ((await page.$('h1')) !== null) {
  // do things with its content
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: Yes, the code was correct but i used a wrong path for the element

Comment: Did you know? If you right click on an element in Chrome DevTools and you select *Copy* : there you are able to copy the exact selector or xpath of an element. After that you can switch to the console tab and with the Chrome api you are able to test the selector's content, so you can prepare it for your puppeteer script. E.g.: `$('#selector').src` should display what you expected, otherwise you need to change on the access, or you need to check if there are more elments with the same selector etc. This may help to find more appropriate selectors. ;)